# Cancelled in transaction in metamask and fund no get it back

Tags: metamask

I was sending 1 eth on uniswap to another token and decided to cancel because it was too long. After that my 1 eth is never come back, do you know why ?

Thank you for your help.

Baptiste

[image: Log activity metamask]

[image: transaction dropped replaced in etherscan, eth value is one]

[image: transaction successfully cancelled, eth value is zero]

Comment: The ether was returned immediately, check the transaction on etherscan. They show a graph with balance analytics. If the wallet used didn't update properly you should contact their support.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I will contact metamask support

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93186/cancelled-in-transaction-in-metamask-and-fund-no-get-it-back